# Float sum with javascript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

i have code jquery but i want a plus 0.00001 for value every second

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     
 setInterval(function()
 { 
   var id = $('.id').attr('rel');
   var st = (parseFloat(id) + parseFloat('0.00001')).toFixed(1);
   $('.id').html(st);
   $('.id').attr('rel',st);

 }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// html output
<span class='id' rel='0.00001'>0.00001</span>
```

Comment: Right, so what's your question?

Comment: `toFixed(1)` is nuking the 5 decimal places you have, and why are you hardcoding `parseFloat('0.00001')` - what's wrong with just `0.00001`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're rounding to 1 decimal place using `toFixed(1)`. Change that to `toFixed(5)` and your code works fine. Although note that converting a string literal to a float is a little redundant, just use the float directly in the addition:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var id = $('.id').attr('rel');
    var st = (parseFloat(id) + 0.00001).toFixed(5);
    $('.id').html(st).attr('rel', st);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// html output
<span class="id" rel="0.00001">0.00001</span>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory McCrossan